# Is there a way to configure Google Project Tango the depth scanning technique and range to less than 4 meters?

Tags: java, google-project-tango, point-clouds

I'm working with the project Tango (java Library) and after I read about Tango techniques to capture the depth data (Structured Light, Time of Flight, and Stereo), I was wondering f there is a way to choose between them through the code?

Another thing, in my app I should only capture depth data within 0.5-2 meters only instead of 0.5-4 meters . I searched on the whole Java API, but I couldn't find anything helpful. So, is there a way to do this?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I tried to search in classes and methods in the Tango Java API to specify the z range but I couldn't anything. Thus, I add an **if** statement when I read the point buffer, which it actually solve my issue. Also, I read that I could change the range by using PCL pass-through, but I didn't need it in my case.

Regarding the depth capturing techniques, I still curios about it. I just want to understand what is the technique that is used in Tango by default. I'm really new to the field of sensors, 3D depth data and heir techniques and I really would like to understand this very well in Tango.